# Why console.log in a loop stops printing when piping to another command?

Tags: node.js, shell, infinite-loop, console.log

I'm using [`fake-words` module](https://github.com/anticoders/fake-words) (`npm install fake-words`) with the following simple code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const fake = require("fake-words");
while (true) {
  console.log(fake.sentence());
}
```

When I run `./genwords.js`, everything works as expected.

However when I pipe into external program (on Ubuntu shell), the generation of words stops after a second.

```
$ ./genwords.js | cat
...
(output generation stops after a second)
$ ./genwords.js | tee
...
(stuck as well)
$ ./genwords.js | pv -l
...
4.64k 0:00:13 [0.00 /s]
```

Same happening when assigning a value to variable to avoid any caching (as precaution after reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51574036/55075), probably not relevant to Node.js):

```
while (true) {
  words = fake.sentence();
  console.log(words);
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

I'm using Node v16 on Ubuntu:

```
$ node --version
v16.13.1
```

Comment: How would assigning to a variable prevent cache? And what cache exactly?

Comment: I did some tests and running `./genwords.js | tee test.txt | pv -l` still seems like it stopped, but words are still generated and saved to the file. It seems like `pv` would be bugged, not node.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Same with `./genwords.js  | tee`, printing on the terminal stops, so not only `pv`.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I've seen some [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51574036/55075) about JVM cache optimizing code (infinite loop), but I doubt it applies to Node.js. So I've tested different syntax as precaution.

Comment: Ok, so it's definitely clogging at some point. Changing `while (true)` to `setInterval` fixes the issue, but it's slower. Also, `./genwords.js | pv > test.txt` works as intended. It's either too much data or too fast or both.

Comment: Displaying any long sentence in a loop will stop after a few seconds in node. I tried to replicate it in c++, but it runs without a problem both with `pv -l` and `tee`.

Comment: I also tried running it on Windows and it works fine. Seems like the issue is with Ubuntu.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski also happens on macOS. My guess is that Node.js does something special when connected to a tty.

Comment: [This](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#a-note-on-process-io) might be relevant:  writes to pipes on POSIX systems (Linux, macOS) are asynchronous. By using a `while (true)` loop, you're blocking the event loop and the output pipe/socket may not get flushed because of that.

Comment: I searched a little more and I didn't find a full answer, but [it's possible to know if output buffer is full] and I checked that and it's full, that's why it's not printing. [There is also  a`drain` event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35801921/5089567) which should happen when buffer is emptied. But the `drain` event never fires in a while loop. Maybe because node is single-threaded.

Comment: Reported a bug at https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/44577

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of `console.log()` in code (such as the `while` loop in your example) that never relinquishes control to the event loop (especially when piped to another process) in Node.js is a longstanding...uh...quirk. It's a lot harder to fix than you might think. Here's the relevant issue in the tracker: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/6379

Or more specifically on the whole handling-when-piped-to-another-process issue: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/1741

You can work around the issue by restructuring the code to relinquish control to the event loop. Here is one possibility.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const fake = require("fake-words");

function getWords() {
  console.log(fake.sentence());
  setImmediate(getWords);
}

getWords()
```